# Laravel 4: Where is the View::make() method located?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to find the make() method of the View facade in Laravel 4. I thought it would be in Illuminate\View\View.php but it's not there. It neither appears in the search results when looking in the [Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the make make here :

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php#L113

It is part of the Envrionment class